# Which kind of progression is applied here?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions

I'm noob is music theory and I want to know which kind of chord progression is applied here to  the first chord?
[image]

The instrument is piano here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have a flawed understanding of what a chord progression is. "which kind of chord progression is applied here to the first chord" is a meaningless sentence, unfortunately - a chord progression requires multiple chords to progress from one to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @filipkv said it is e minor, specifically two e minor chords. It's a chord progression that is missing the progression. In music theory terms it is literally `i-i`, `e-e`.

If you play it you will get the feeling it isn't doing very much or moving slowly.

Also, the term chord progression isn't applied to one chord necessarily, but to the entire set of chords.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's just E minor. Two different voicings.
Technically the first chord is not a chord, but an interval. But it's implied to be E minor.